# Why does this recursive function behave different than intended?

Tags: c++, if-statement, recursion, binary-tree

I am writing a binary tree and I am stuck on a search function that takes a value x and determines if it is a leaf in the tree or not.

Here is what I have:

```
bool search(Node<T>* &currentNode, const T& x) const
{
    /* Base Case */
    if ( currentNode != nullptr && (leaf(currentNode) == true) && currentNode->data == x )
    {
        return true;
    }

    /* Recursive Case */
    else {

        if (currentNode != nullptr)
        {
        search(currentNode->left, x);
        search(currentNode->right, x);
        }

        //If first if condition is not met for all values then value must not exist
        return false;

        }


bool leaf(Node<T>* currentNode) const 
{
    if (currentNode != nullptr)
    {
    return ((currentNode->left == nullptr && currentNode->right == nullptr) ? true : false);        
    }
    else  
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code always returns false, why is the first IF statement never triggered?

EDIT:
Code calling search:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)           
            if ((t.search(i) == true) ? cout << "LEAF FOUND: " << i  << endl : cout << " NOT A LEAF: " << i << endl);
```

Comment: Please show the code calling `search()`.

Comment: Maybe your tree has no leaves that have the matching value of `x` ?

Comment: Added the code calling search. As you can see I am testing every value from 0 to 100, and the tree is initialized with 100 values from 0 to 100.

Comment: 1) if `currentNode->data == x`, shouldn't `search` return `true` regardless of whether it's a leaf or not?  i.e. don't you store data in all the nodes, or is it really only the leaves?  2) when you recursively call search, you ignore what it returns.  Try `return search(currentNode->left, x) || search(currentnode->right, x);`

Comment: BTW: your `leaf()` function simplifies to `return !(currentNode || currentNode->left || currentNode->right);`.  Simple and concise is beautiful ;-).

Comment: Maybe he wants to skip matching values that are not leaves

Comment: On a side note - I'm sure this is me being stupid, but search(..) has two arguments - you're only passing one. Do you have an overload/wrapper to use it via the object which calls it? I guess something like `search(const <T>& x){return search(*this, x);}`, or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes, good catch. It is overloaded and I'm using the public version as an interface between the private data and the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dealing with recursion can be tricky :D.

unless the root node is a leaf your code will always return  return `false`
your code returns true to the function that made the call not all the way back to the original caller ( before recursion)

let's say your tree had three elements and the item was in the left leaf
so in the root node you called yourself with the left node so it returned true to the caller ( the root node) , the root node does nothing with this and just continue executing.

this can be simply solved simply by adding an if statement to check for the returned value of the functions you called

```
if (currentNode != nullptr)
{
    if(search(currentNode->left, x)) return true;
    if(search(currentNode->right, x)) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: That was very helpful, I think I finally understand recursion. On that note, How are the search calls executed? Do both if statements execute in one search call? Are all the left and right nodes visited with this method?

Comment: No this method stop visiting nodes once it finds the element,if you want to visit every node you shouldn't return unless you finish visiting all your kids

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't return the boolean from the search method back:

```
if (currentNode != nullptr)
{
search(currentNode->left, x);
search(currentNode->right, x);
}
```

You always will return false.